# Reputation milestones, dreams, and electric sheep

Tags: discussion, reputation

In the waning days of 2011, when I was nigh upon the threshold of 2000 reputation points on SO, I had an interesting experience. I debated with myself about even posting this but, heck, why not share a bit of amusement...

Truth be told, the evening before I crossed the 2000-point mark *I dreamed about it*. I dreamed that I got up that morning and, as I do on occasion, I logged in to SO to check the latest questions and saw that, yes, I had made it across the 2K threshold! So I patted myself on the back, relished the moment with a satisfactory grin... and then went on about my business. When I later woke up... I did pretty much the same thing.

My questions surrounding this surreal event are many:

- Is that all there is?
- Is this as good as it gets?
- Am I worthy to wield this newly bestowed power (the power to edit posts) ?
- Should I just put it behind me and go answer another question?
- Do androids really dream of electric sheep?
- Do I need to "get a life"?

*“Ah, Bartleby!  Ah, humanity!”*

Comment: I was chatting with one of our moderators on what happens after you pass the 10K mark. [She promised there would be cake](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2783605#2783605).

Comment: In a quirky twist of fate, the universe has seen fit that this question about thresholds in SO carried me across the 500-point threshold on MSO!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Yes.
- Yes.
- No, not really.
- Yes.
- They dream of electric unicorns.
- Yes.

*Doh!* (Homer Simpson)

Comment: One cannot hope for a more...concise answer--much obliged, Oded! (Not sure I quite follow your reasoning on question 2, though :-).